# EXECUTE AS does not default to a Schema Name

Tags: t-sql

After having done extensive research online, I am reaching out to you guys to resolve this issue. My database adopts schema based approach

> i.e, dbo.TableA schema1.TableA exist in the same database.

I am using impersonation with to switch between schemas.

```
Create procedure spx_test (@username nvarchar(10) 
As
Execute as Login = @username  -- this user has it's default schema set to schema1
Select * from TableA
```

The above SP always defaults to dbo i.e, results from dbo.TableA are fetched. In contrast, if I run as a SQL block outside SP, it works like a charm. I am not sure of what I am missing here.

P.S- I have tried Grant impersonate (didn't work). Please note that connection login is different from the login used in the SP.

Thanks in advance!

**Update**

The above SP works if I convert it to a dynamic SQL

Answer (score 2):

See [SQL default schema resolution in Stored Procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27357352/sql-default-schema-resolution-in-stored-procedure).

The behavior is described in https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191132(v=sql.105).aspx: "Inside a stored procedure, object names used with statements (for example, SELECT or INSERT) that are not schema-qualified default to the schema of the stored procedure."

Also see this suggestion (closed as "Won't fix"): https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/272964/using-default-schema-in-stored-procedures

Comment: Thanks, that's definitely useful.